# How to display values from subarrays in pairs and alternate class attribute order?

Tags: php, html, css, toggle, grouping

How can I display every two subarrays' NAME values in separate divs while toggling the order of their class attributes, and wrap the pair of divs in a containing div using a loop?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
<?
    $arr = array(
            array('ID'=>1, 'NAME'=>'a'),
            array('ID'=>2, 'NAME'=>'b'),
            array('ID'=>3, 'NAME'=>'c'),
            array('ID'=>4, 'NAME'=>'d'),
            array('ID'=>5, 'NAME'=>'f'),
            array('ID'=>6, 'NAME'=>'g')
    );
    $i = 0;
    $el_in_row = 2;
    foreach($arr as $key => $arItem)
    {
        $i++;
        $odd = ($i%2) ? true : false;
        $class = ($odd === true)?'vertical':'horizontal';
        ?>
        <div class="<?=$class;?>">
            <?=$arItem['NAME'];?>
        </div>
        <? ?>
        <? if($i >= $el_in_row): $i = 0;?>
            </div><div class="row clearfix">
        <? endif;?>
        <?
    }
?>
</div>
```

Returns:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">a</div>
    <div class="horizontal">b</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">c</div>
    <div class="horizontal">d</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">f</div>
    <div class="horizontal">g</div>
</div>
```

But I need this result:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">a</div>    // vertical class first
    <div class="horizontal">b</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="horizontal">c</div>  // horizontal class first
    <div class="vertical">d</div>
</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">f</div>    // vertical class first
    <div class="horizontal">g</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your code is working check [this](http://phpio.net/s/4ch3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I can make it any faster / DRYer than this:

(Bear in mind, I am using the subarrays' indexes to find odd/even -- not the ID element values.)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a9d294a2e1ddfadfe5f4aafbb2062a3da003ad0))

```
$arr = array(
        array('ID'=>1, 'NAME'=>'a'),
        array('ID'=>2, 'NAME'=>'b'),
        array('ID'=>3, 'NAME'=>'c'),
        array('ID'=>4, 'NAME'=>'d'),
        array('ID'=>5, 'NAME'=>'f'),
        array('ID'=>6, 'NAME'=>'g')
);
$classes=['vertical','horizontal'];
foreach($arr as $i=>$a){
    if(!($i & 1)){  // if non-odd number; bitwise operator is ~x10 faster than modulus
        echo "<div class=\"row clearfix\"><div class=\"",reset($classes),"\">{$a['NAME']}</div>";
    }else{
        echo "<div class=\"",next($classes),"\">{$a['NAME']}</div></div>";
        $classes=array_reverse($classes); // re-order the array every odd $i iteration
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">a</div>
    <div class="horizontal">b</div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="horizontal">c</div>
    <div class="vertical">d</div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="vertical">f</div>
    <div class="horizontal">g</div>
</div>
```

---

Here is another method that provides the same output with greater efficiency because it has fewer iterated function calls:

```
$arr = array(
        array('ID'=>1, 'NAME'=>'a'),
        array('ID'=>2, 'NAME'=>'b'),
        array('ID'=>3, 'NAME'=>'c'),
        array('ID'=>4, 'NAME'=>'d'),
        array('ID'=>5, 'NAME'=>'f'),
        array('ID'=>6, 'NAME'=>'g')
);
$classes=['vertical','horizontal'];
$x=0;
foreach(array_chunk(array_column($arr,'NAME'),2) as $a){
    echo "<div class=\"row clearfix\">\n";
        echo "\t<div class=\"{$classes[$x]}\">{$a[0]}</div>\n";
        echo "\t<div class=\"{$classes[$x^=1]}\">{$a[1]}</div>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

- `array_column()` stores all of the `NAME` values in a new, indexed, single dimensional array.
- `array_chunk()` restructures the generated array into an array of arrays holding two indexed elements each.
- The "magic" behind the toggling of `$classes` values comes from the [XOR bitwise operator `^`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).  The effect in this method is that the second access of `$classes` on each iteration of the loop changes `$x` from `0` to `1` or `1` to `0`.
- The elements inside of `$a` are always `0` and `1`, so they can be accessed in a regular/static fashion.

Comment: Returns not what I need.
I need such a sequence ...
first pairs vertical & horizontal
next pairs horizontal & vertical
and etc

Comment: @Zak My mistake.  Thank you for clarifying.  My new answer yields the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

A convenient array function in PHP to build pairs (or triples, ...) is  [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$pairs = array_chunk($arr, 2);
```

You can then do an iteration inside an iteration when you want to output it.

As you want only the *name* columns inside each pair, the next convenient array function is [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) which turns the pair into a pair of names.

```
$names = array_column($pair, 'NAME');
```

Next to that combining these names with the classes you want to output, [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine) is useful to key the names with the classes:

```
array_combine(['vertical', 'horizontal'], $names);
```

To bundle this together, you can make use of a **Generator** function that yield these pairs from your input array. A function has the benefit that you can control the parameters, I use default values here to match your example:

```
function chunk_columns(array $array, $column = 'NAME', array $keys = ['vertical', 'horizontal']) {

    $pairs = array_chunk($array, count($keys));

    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        yield array_combine(
            $keys,
            array_column($pair, $column)
        );
    }
}
```

A usage example of that function would then look like (using PHP inside HTML for templating):

```
<?php foreach (chunk_columns($arr) as $chunk) { ?>

  <div class="row clearfix">
      <?php foreach ($chunk as $class => $name) { ?>
        <div class="<?= $class ?>"><?= $name ?></div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Take care as you interpolate the HTML with variables, to properly encode their values as HTML, see [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). I left that out to make this more exemplary, in a real life situation the output needs proper HTML encoding.

So now for the output with your example data to complete the answer:

```
  <div class="row clearfix">
              <div class="vertical">a</div>
              <div class="horizontal">b</div>
        </div>


  <div class="row clearfix">
              <div class="vertical">c</div>
              <div class="horizontal">d</div>
        </div>


  <div class="row clearfix">
              <div class="vertical">f</div>
              <div class="horizontal">g</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I like the array_chunk approach but the OP doesn't want `ID`

Comment: @mickmackusa: I've overlooked that, edited the answer, it's still with array_chunk and a bit more then is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The loop should look like this: for odd rows start with `<div class="row clearfix">`, even rows end (close) with `</div>`.

```
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $ar)
{
  $i++;
  if($i%2) //odd rows
  {
    echo '<div class="row clearfix">'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '  <div class="vertical">'.$ar['NAME'].'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
  else //even rows
  {
    echo '  <div class="horizontal">'.$ar['NAME'].'</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```